# Call to undefined function wp_embed_register_handler()

Tags: errors

I have a Wordpress website that is still under development. I was working on this website till end of Feb, 2021 and hold all works due to COVID crises. Till that date, website was working. Now I have resumed my work and just looking into website. But now, website is throwing an error "**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_embed_register_handler()**"

I have also crossed the file "wp-includes/embed.php" file in which this function exists and function is already defined before calling it. You can see attached screenshot of whole error tracing.

[image]

I am not getting this error on all pages but almost every pages. I am not able to understand why I am getting this error even I have not touched anything on website from last 3-4 months. And it was working fine when I was working last.

Can someone please help on this? I am not very experienced in Wordpress but have intermediate knowledge.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This looks like a failed/incomplete update. You should be able to fix with a manual update https://wordpress.org/support/article/updating-wordpress/#manual-update